# Run python script in laravel

Tags: python, php, laravel, opencv

There is a python script for face recognition that i want to modify and run it in my laravel application to give access to the users to a page using face recognition. But i have no idea how to do that.

Here is the original html ( not the one of my application) :
you take a snapshot and compare the image with images you have in a folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<nav class="navbar text-white navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
Login 
</a>
</nav>
     <p>

    </p>
    <div class="container text-center bordered" style="width:280px">
    <form action="login.py" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <video onclick="snapshot(this);" width=250 height=250 id="video" controls autoplay></video>
    <br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-sm text-left">
    <br>
    <input type="text" accept="image/png" hidden name="current_image" id="current_image">
       <button  onclick="login()" class="btn-dark" value="login">Login </button>
       <br>
       <br>
    </form>
    </div>
      <canvas  id="myCanvas" width="400" height="350" hidden></canvas>  
  </body>
  <script>
      //--------------------
      // GET USER MEDIA CODE
      //--------------------
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                             navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                             navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                             navigator.msGetUserMedia);

      var video;
      var webcamStream;
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
           navigator.getUserMedia (

              // constraints
              {
                 video: true,
                 audio: false
              },

              // successCallback
              function(localMediaStream) {
                  video = document.querySelector('video');
                 video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
                 webcamStream = localMediaStream;
              },

              // errorCallback
              function(err) {
                 console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
              }
           );
        } else {
           console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
        }  



      var canvas, ctx;

      function init() {
        // Get the canvas and obtain a context for
        // drawing in it
mcanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        ctx = mcanvas.getContext('2d');
      }

      function login() {
         // Draws current image from the video element into the canvas
        ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,mcanvas.width,mcanvas.height);
        var dataURL = mcanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
         document.getElementById("current_image").value=dataURL;

      }

  </script>
</html>
```

and the python :

```
#!"C:\Users\aya-i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"
import cgi
from base64 import b64decode
import face_recognition
formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
face_match=0

image=formData.getvalue("current_image")
email=formData.getvalue("email")
data_uri = image
header, encoded = data_uri.split(",", 1)
data = b64decode(encoded)

with open("image.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)

got_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("image.png")

existing_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("students/"+email+".jpg")

got_image_facialfeatures = face_recognition.face_encodings(got_image)[0]

existing_image_facialfeatures = face_recognition.face_encodings(existing_image)[0]

results= face_recognition.compare_faces([existing_image_facialfeatures],got_image_facialfeatures)

if(results[0]):
    face_match=1
else:
    face_match=0

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

if(face_match==1):
    print("<script>alert('welcome ",email," ')</script>")
else:
    print("<script>alert('face not recognized')</script>")
```

Comment: PHP has function `exec()` to run external programs and maybe you could use it to run python code but I would use Python only to recognize face and rest I would do in Laravel - it means display HTML with form, get values from form, send it to python script, get result from python, and display result in HTMl

Comment: Thank you but how can i pass in my controller the values of the form to my python script ?

Comment: `exec()` get program name and arguments - `exec("python script.py arg1 arg2")`. If you have text values then use directly strings, if you have images then save them in files and use path as arguments. And in Python uses `sys.argv` to get there arguments. And use `print()` to send values back to `PHP` and it should get it as text. Simply use Google to find more information about `exec()`. Eventually in PHP you can save data in file and open this file in Python, and in Python save results in file and open it in PHP.

Comment: see PHP documentation: [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php). The only problem can be that on some servers `exec()` can be blocked for security reason.

Comment: I tried this simple code to check if it's working : test.py : `import sys  x=sys.argv[1]  print(x)` and in my controller :`$output = exec("python test.py $request->email"); dd($output);` and i get a :  ""

Comment: Did i do something wrong ?

Comment: did you check if you don't get any error mesage when you run it?  Maybe start with somethis simpler - like in documentation `echo exec('whoami');` (if you run it in LInux)

Comment: And next `echo exec("python -V");` to see if it can run `python`. if it has problem then you can try with full path `echo exec("/full/path/to/python -V");`. etc. The same it may need `/full/path/to/test.py`. And first youc try with constant argument - ie.`exec("python test.py HelloWorld")`. Step by step you check it to get when it may have problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any external commands such as unix terminal commands, python command and ... should be run with PHP's `exec()` function. This function runs your commands and has an option to get the output of your command, you have to handle the error and success output yourself.

Comment: Thank you but how can i pass in my controller the values of the form to my python script ?

Comment: @Nielson your command is a string such as "cd ~ && ls" if you are in your controller you have tyo create your command string with the data given from a user then you run `exec('cd ~ && ls', $output);` the `$output` is your output.